# Is it possible with GIT to remove the file only from the index?

Tags: git, git-svn

```
GIT rm filename
```

remove the file from the index as well as from your working directory.
Is it possible to remove the file **only** from the index ?

thank you,
Alessandro DS

Comment: I just answered your question on database.yaml when you deleted it. It was a good question...

Comment: Sorry, I removed the question because I thought it was a bad question e very bad written.
I've rewrote it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142418/files-in-gitignore
thank you

Comment: @aleds: I forgot to mention you could have undeleted your own first question instead of recreating it. Too late now. For what it worth, I have copied my original answer to your new *identical* question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`git rm --cached`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html):

> *--cached*
>
> > Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.