# Files in gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-svn

I have a repository with a rails app in the production Server.

In the repo there is the .gitignore file:

```
...
    config/database.yaml 
...
```

Every developing client have a cloned repo with different config/database.yaml.

My problem is this:

database.yaml is in .gitignore, then when I run git clone (on the server) the database.yaml will not be created, but I need it.

I thought than I am doing wrong something.
Can you see where is my mistake ?

thank you,
Alessandro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my projects, I usually make a copy of a usable database config in a database.example.yml, then when someone clones the projects, copy the database.example.yml to database.yml and make the needed changes.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(here is a copy of [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141571/files-in-gitignore/3141663#3141663) to your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141571/files-in-gitignore))</sup>

You don't version the right file.

You should version:

- a `database.yaml.template`
- 2 files (one for server values, and one for generic client values)
- 1 script able to build `database.yaml` on the checkout

That script would be called by the [smudge step of a filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728).

[image]

The resulting `database.yaml` would be "private" (never versioned/pushed or pulled), and can be modified at will.

Answer (score 1):

keep a template like database.example.yml as robertokl suggests

when you deploy your application to production server you should be using something like [capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) and part of your capistrano recipe(script) will be to rename that file or to place the correct database.yml file in the config dir

Answer (score 0):

All these database.yaml files have something in common: you can commit a base configuration, and let all your developing clients maintain a fork of it in their own branches with appropriate settings filled in; they can rebase on top of the base configuration in the master branch whenever it gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

aleds - it's generally a bad idea to have your database.yml in a repository which is why you see it in .gitignore. robertokl is right about providing a template file.